# Can't get Docker to expand ARG define at head of file

Tags: windows, docker

I have a Dockerfile that is based on Windows 10 that I want to use with conan. My problem is that I cannot get Docker to expand an ARG I defined at the head of the file. In this sample:

```
ARG conan_repository=https://feeds.genetec.com/artifactory/api/conan/conan
ARG conan_remote=genetec

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903

RUN conan remote add ${conan_remote ${conan_repository}
```

or

```
RUN conan remote add $conan_remote $conan_repository
```

always ends up as

```
C:\>conan remote list
conan-center: https://conan.bintray.com [Verify SSL: True]
$conan_remote: $conan_repository [Verify SSL: True]
```

Adding the conan remote manually after I connected to the image works well.

I can't seen to find anything on the docs about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `ARG` lines after the `FROM` line.

In the Dockerfile reference, see [Understand how ARG and FROM interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact).  In particular:

> An `ARG` declared before a `FROM` is outside of a build stage, so it can’t be used in any instruction after a `FROM`.

You can use `ARG` to control which image you’re starting from (like picking a specific tag for the base image), in which case `ARG` has to come first.  Otherwise, you need to put `ARG` after `FROM`, and if the same `ARG` is used in multiple parts of a multi-stage Dockerfile, you need to repeat it for each stage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Global args value as a default then you should declare them in each stage without value so it will pick a value from global args, if override then it will use the override value, If not then it will use the default.

Let see this demo Dockerfile

```
ARG version_default=v1

FROM alpine:latest as base1
ARG version_default
ENV version=$version_default
RUN echo ${version} # value v1 with default value as environment variable.
RUN echo ${version_default}# value v1 as args
```

To make it work in your Dockerfile you need something like that

```
ARG conan_repository=https://feeds.genetec.com/artifactory/api/conan/conan
ARG conan_remote=genetec

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903
ARG conan_repository
ARG conan_remote
ENV conan_remote=$conan_remote
ENV ARG conan_repository=$ARG conan_repository
RUN conan remote add ${conan_remote ${conan_repository}
```

Remember Args only available at build time where ENV available at run time of the container.

or with multi-stage, you can try to extend from base image.

Comment: Did you try the second? Because I just can't make it work.

Comment: yes ```ARG conan_repository=https://feeds.genetec.com/artifactory/api/conan/conan
ARG conan_remote=genetec

FROM alpine
ARG conan_repository

RUN echo "$conan_repository"
``` I tried this as can not run widnow image

Comment: There must be something with Windows because I can do the same with Linux too.

Comment: Yes really sorry for that Just checked with Linux. my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

So I got my answer [from](https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-consume-arg-or-env-variables-in-run-commands/25467/3) the Docker forums: Docker makes the value available to Windows as a variable so in order to access the value I need to use a Windows variable.