# Docker args in Docker compose does not pass into Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, quarkus

I am using the latest Docker Toolbox under Windows 10 to build the native image for Quarkus applciations.

```sh
$ docker -v
Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89e8a
```

The docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3.7' # specify docker-compose version

services:
  blogdb:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: blogdb
      POSTGRES_USER: user
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql

  post-service: 
    image: hantsy/quarkus-post-service
    build: 
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: src/main/docker/Dockerfile.multistage
      args:
        - QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL
    environment:
      QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://blogdb:5432/blogdb
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" #specify ports forewarding
    depends_on:
      - blogdb
```

And the Dockerfile:

```
## Stage 1 : build with maven builder image with native capabilities
FROM quay.io/quarkus/centos-quarkus-maven:19.1.1 AS build
ARG QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL
RUN echo "QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL>>>: $QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL"
ENV QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL $QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn -U dependency:go-offline dependency:resolve-plugins -Pnative
COPY src/ /usr/src/app/src/
USER root
RUN chown -R quarkus /usr/src/app
USER quarkus
RUN mvn clean package -Pnative -Dquarkus.datasource.url=$QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL
## -DskipTests -Dmaven.test.skip=true

## Stage 2 : create the docker final image
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal
WORKDIR /work/
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/*-runner /work/application
RUN chmod 775 /work
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```

The **echo** always prints blank for the arg: `QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL`.

I have tried to change the **args** to `QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL=${QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL}`, it still prints blank.

It can not read the environment defined in docker-compose.yaml file as [Docker docs described](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args) said.

If set value as a string directly, it workw, eg. `QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL="test"`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-consume-arg-or-env-variables-in-run-commands/25467/3), you need to follow window PowerShell syntax.

It seems that you must use $env:arg or %arg% when using PowerShell or cmd, but you must use $arg when using docker commands.

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver
ARG QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL=some_default_value
RUN echo %QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL%
ENV QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL %QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL%
```

[Can't get Docker to expand ARG define at head of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57873314/cant-get-docker-to-expand-arg-define-at-head-of-file/57874653?noredirect=1#comment102195853_57874653)

> It seems that you must use $env:arg or %arg% when using powershell or
>   cmd, but you must use $arg when using docker commands.

Comment: I am using Docker Toolbox(Virtualbox instead of Hyper-V), which includes a bash shell.

Comment: No, it did not work. Docker Toolbox works a little wired, unlike Docker in Linux,  I encountered some network/folder mapping issues in the past. Maybe try it on Linux later.